# creating a hiveQL query that uses UDF function that can return column names

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to create a Hive UDF function that returns specific column names based on some value say retreivecol(age).If the age is 20 then return the list of column names to be used in select query like 'name,email,fbuserid,friend list ' etc and if the age is less than 20 return 'name' alone.So I want my HIVE QL query to look like

select retreivecol(age) from User_Data;

The above query just prints the name of the columns like 'name,email,fbuserid,friendslist' etc as opposed to treating them as column names and filtering based on the same.Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a UDF is the right place to do this, as UDF's simply see the value passed to them, they don't really have access to the whole table structure.

Instead, could you do this in a nested table?

```
select name,email,id FROM
(
  select
    name,
    if(age < 20, email, NULL) as email,
    if(age < 20, id, NULL) as id
  FROM mytable

) a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am looking at multiple conditions and basically I have to dynamically determine the fields i have to include in the select statement based on a UDF functions .Something like funct(xqy)==123 then return name,email,age else if funct (xqy)==234 return age,email etc.I have multiple conditions like the same and I dont want to write everything as if statements in HiveQL

Comment: how about a udf that takes all of those arguments, then returns like a comma-separated list of valid values? eg: getStuff(age,email,id) => "frank". You could even have a second step to split the list into individual columns if you wanted.